# I keep getting error when the loading JS file via Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get node.js working now therefore I try to write a simple test function in JavaScript and name it score.js.

```
var score = 61;

if (score >= 60)
    console.log("pass");
else
    console.log("failed");
```

I try to run this but this happened[image]

How may i fix this issue?

Comment: try using this command :  node score.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to execute your scripts using the `node` executable, like: `node score.js`. Otherwise Windows will try to execute your javascript file with Microsoft's JScript implementation, which is *very* different.